# What kind of control system does move_base have?

Tags: control, ros, navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm trying to wrap my head around **which node exactly** does the control system for moving a specific distance in the Navigation stack (using current velocity from /cmd_vel). I came to the conclusion that move_base is responsible for this, but now I'm wondering: what kind of control system does it implement? How does it know what cmd_vel to publish in order to reach the specific distance it must go? Is it a PID controller or something?

I'm mostly asking this just to make sure that I understand this right... I basically want to make sure that my robot moves to the designated destination in a controlled manner (not just full speed until it reaches target then stops and overshoots)...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94911/what-kind-of-control-system-does-move_base-have?/) by [basheersubei](https://answers.ros.org/users/7676/basheersubei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-11-01**:
Which planner are you using and what ROS version?

**Comment by [basheersubei](https://answers.ros.org/users/7676/basheersubei/) on 2013-11-01**:
I haven't started working on the Navigation stack, because I need to first figure out my base_controller (and I need to find out what it should expect from Navigation). Basically, does Navigation take care of going from one point to another in a controlled manner (without overshoot)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The local planner is the controller, taking in the global plan and outputting the cmd_vel. Specifically, the low level control (at least for the DWA planner) is handled here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/base_local_planner/src/latched_stop_rotate_controller.cpp

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [basheersubei](https://answers.ros.org/users/7676/basheersubei/) on 2013-11-04**:
thank you for your reply. Do you have any idea where I can learn more about the latched_stop_rotate_controller and what to expect of it? Should I basically not worry about implementing a control system (for reaching goals) in my base_controller?

**Comment by [basheersubei](https://answers.ros.org/users/7676/basheersubei/) on 2013-11-04**:
I noticed I can find more about it here http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner#LatchedStopRotateController . I will attempt to do the Navigation tutorials for now. Thanks again!